# Does MarkLogic's Node.js API support configured search options?

Tags: marklogic

In the REST API, I can store configured search options and then use them by hitting `GET http://server:port/v1/search?options=foo`. Looking in the Node.js API documentation, I don't see any reference to using configured search options like that. Does the Node Client API support the use of configured options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's intended.

The Node.js API specifies the query on the client instead of maintaining part of the query definition on the client and part on the server.

For cases where it is beneficial to separate query definition from query criteria, one possible approach is to create a small library with functions that takes query criteria and returns queries.

Hoping that's useful,

Comment: Thanks, Erik. In my case, I've got several path range indexes that I want to use from /v1/values. Not being able to refer to configured options means I need to explicitly list the full paths both in MarkLogic and at the Node.js layer, instead of Node being able to refer to a label. I'll work around by using HTTP calls instead.

Comment: Given that the Node.js API can build a values lookup (as documented in   http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_55308), I'm wondering whether awareness of the paths can be maintained as module constants encapsulated within a small library that can build either query clauses or values lookups.

Comment: The 'yes, that's intended' is rather confusing, nor true. It is perfectly valid, and possible to refer to search options saved on the server.

Comment: The query builder in the Node.js API isn't designed to work with query options on the server but, instead, to encourage defining the query on the client.  The Node.js API does provide an escape hatch (as you note in your answer) but that circumvents the query builder and is not the expected pattern of use.

Comment: It doesn't circumvent the query builder at all, just uses it differently..

Answer (score 1):

(Credits to Mike Wooldridge for sharing this in the past)

In the Node.js Client API, you can reference saved search options by executing a query:

https://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/documents.html#query

and passing in a CombinedQueryDefinition as the first argument:

https://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/documents.html#.CombinedQueryDefinition

with an optionsName property.

HTH!