# Use persisted query options in MarkLogic NodeJS client for suggestion

Tags: node.js, marklogic

In MarkLogic REST API `/v1/suggest`, I can use constraint defined in persisted query options in `partial-q`. I am not sure how to accomplish the same task using the MarkLogic NodeJS client. According to the documentation, it seems the only way I can reference persisted query options is through **combined query**. I see it works for document **search**, but I don't know if and how it would work for **suggest**.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_57610

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure it works with typeahead suggestions, but support for persisted search options was built-in as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58624280/918496

Comment: Hi @grtjn. As I discussed in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67328037/3546482), the `Document.suggest` method does not pass `optionsName` to the underneath REST API as the `Document.query` method does.

Answer (score 0):

Going over the source code, I see that support for persisted query options is only available for the `Documents.query` method: https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/blob/master/lib/documents.js#L1862

```js
var optionsName = wrapper.optionsName;
...
if (optionsName != null) {
  endpoint += '&options='+optionsName;
}
```

It is straightforward to do the same for the `Documents.suggest` method - not sure why it is missing. For now, I just need to override the `Documents.suggest` method to add the several lines of code shown above.